# Undefined form style

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, simple-form, jquery-chosen

I create some filter from my task list. Use `simple_form` and `chosen-rails`. But my form looks awful.

My form has next code:

```
= simple_form_for @search do |f|
  = f.collection_select(:user_id_in, User.all, :id, :name, {},{:multiple => "multiple", "data-placeholder" => "Select user"})
  = f.button :submit, "Submit"
```

And my `coffee` file:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#search_user_id_in').chosen()
```

It was look:

```
<div id="search_user_id_in_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-multi" style="width: 42px;">
```

Where did this value: `style="width: 42px;`? `Chosen` or `simple_form`?
I must override each `<div>` element in `css` file with `!important`?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is from chosen...
I use chosen, but I use it straight as a JS file and CSS so I have the flexibility to go find the 42px and update it accordingly... Do you have a Chosen.js or Chosen.css somewhere?

Comment: No. I `required` them in `applictaion` files(`.js` and `.css`). But I have check a `chosen.css` from https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/blob/master/chosen/chosen.css and not found any string with `42px`. It looks weird